# SAMPLE BY and FILL to generate intervals between two arbitrary dates

Tags: database, time-series, questdb

I have a table with some data in QuestDB. If I want to downsample by day and interpolate empty rows for the days where I have no data I can do it via

```
SELECT timestamp, AVG(energy) AS energy FROM production
SAMPLE BY 1d FILL(NULL)
```

However, that query starts on the first timestamp I have on my table and finish on the last one. Let's say I have data only for the past 15 days, but I want to return a row for every day in the past two months and one week in the future. How can I do that?

The use case is statistics reporting in an IoT application, where i want to present to the user a chart of energy consumption between two dates, even if there is no data available for the whole period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that `SAMPLE BY` combined with `FILL` will only interpolate rows for the missing intervals between the first and last available time on record for your query.

However you can use a workaround using a `UNION` to add the boundaries around your dataset.

As an example, you can execute this query on the `gas_prices` table available at the [public Questdb demo](https://demo.questdb.io).

```
WITH full_range AS (  
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT to_timestamp('1999-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS timestamp, NULL AS galon_price
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM gas_prices
    UNION 
    SELECT to_timestamp('2023-02-20', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS timestamp, NULL AS galon_price
  ) TIMESTAMP(timestamp)
  ) 
SELECT timestamp, sum(galon_price) FROM full_range SAMPLE BY 3M FILL(NULL);
```

Please note if you combine this query with `ORDER BY`, at the time of this posts there is an open issue that's [being addressed at the GitHub repo](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/3010).